# Log in failed to google play game services

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

Here is the situation :
I have integrated google play game services for leaderboards and achievements. While I was testing the app using android studio everything was working perfectly.

I generated the APK and uploaded it to the Android play store. After uploading it to the play store the app is not able to log the user in and shows a pop up saying "**Sign in failed. Check internet connection**" (The internet was working fine).

*Side note:*
I have generated two linked apps with the same package as I got the SHA1 wrong the first time

Answer (score 0):

without any code we can't much help you, but 90% your mistake is as follows:
to make your app work with google play services you need to register your app ID and the SHA2 of your developer key, you were using the debug key while testing and got it to work

you generated the signed APK to publish it on the store with a different key, and thus your SHA2 finger print changed, thus the google play services are rejecting your sign in. you need to add the SHA2 of your developer key

without code this is everything I can do for you now :)

Comment: How do I get the SHA2 of my developer key.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of resources on how to do this, including the official google play services docs